# jQuery UI draggable events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery and jQuery UI to make some divs draggable, and this is working.

```
$(".bluebox").draggable({
  revert: true,
  start: function() {
    $("#bluebox").css("background-color", "#43c8d4");
  },
  drag: function() {
    $("#bluebox").css("background-color", "green");
  }
});
```

However, the start and and drag events are not causing the css to run.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqop6ho6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selectors are wrong.

The element you are trying to target has a class named `bluebox`, not an id, therefore the selector should be `$(".bluebox")` rather than `$("#bluebox")` - [(updated example)](https://jsfiddle.net/c800u1Le/).

---

As a side note, since you are re-selecting the `.bluebox` element within the `.draggable()` method, you can use the `this` keyword since it will reference that element:

```
$(".bluebox").draggable({
  revert: true,
  start: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#43c8d4");
  },
  drag: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
  }
});
```

It's also worth pointing out that the `start` callback won't have any effect since it will be overridden by the `drag` method's styling changes.

Comment: Hah, solved by changing a single character! And thanks for pointing out an even better solution, the `this` keyword.